# Mediapipe: How to implement real time gesture recognition in multi hand tracking module

Tags: mediapipe

How can we modify mediapipe code to get real time gesture recognition of a basic set of gestures. I ran multi hand tracking apk but it could not recognise basic gestures as promised in https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/on-device-real-time-hand-tracking-with.html .

Answer (score 0):

So far, I see two ways:

1. Use a pre-trained model wrapped within a calculator.
2. Train a model using the 21 landmarks by collecting points for each gesture and normalizing the landmarks' x, y, z values.

Comment: i am using their landmark model, i input the image and got output of shape (1,63), can you tell me what this is  and how to use them to train model

Comment: I checked out the examples for Linux desktop using C++. What I did was identify the possitions of the landmarks with respect to their locations in palms and manually wrote detectors for gestures by calculating presence of polygon shapes.

Comment: https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/414      i found this link useful for my particular problem hope it will be useful for other too